# Basics: ARIMA in R, resulting in NA in input

Tags: r, time-series, data-entry

If someone could put me on the right track, Id appreciate it!

I'm receiving "NA" for all of my rows after input them into the matrix, before using ARIMA.

Thanks!

```
 library(fma)
 library(forecast)

 #Data prep for time series
 Hist_INPUT_TS <- read.csv("file.csv")

 #XYZ   
 ARIMAX_INPUT_Raw <- read.csv("file.csv")
 region="XYZ"
 bucol=2;

 names(ARIMAX_INPUT_Raw)
 head(ARIMAX_INPUT_Raw)

 Final_Forecast = matrix( ,   nrow=21,    ncol=1) 

 print(Final_Forecast)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 names(ARIMAX_INPUT_Raw)
 [1] "XYZ"  "Time"
 > head(ARIMAX_INPUT_Raw)
   AMS   Time
 1 160270.3 2008Q1
 2 167053.0 2008Q2
 3 161498.5 2008Q3
 4 134152.0 2008Q4
 5 104948.6 2009Q1
 6 120187.5 2009Q2
 > Final_Forecast = matrix( ,   nrow=21,    ncol=1)
 > print(Final_Forecast)
  [,1]
  [1,]   NA
  **[N,]**
```

Comment: `matrix( , nrow=21, ncol=1)` makes a 21 x 1 empty (full of `NA`s) matrix; you need to put something in the first argument to fill it. What are you trying to do?

Comment: matrix(nrow = 32, ncol = 2) Would this create the rows of predictor tables from my table and both columns, one for the predictor and one for the time unit)?

Comment: Nope, gives me two rows of NA

Comment: Voting to close because you asked to print out a matrix filled with NA.

Answer (score 0):

`matrix( , nrow=21, ncol=1)` did not need to be included.